# Problem with Image in DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, image, datagridview

Good morning,

I want to show image (16*16px png file) in DataGridView. This Grid has 3 columns: text cell, text cell, image cell.
Here is sample, how I try set image:

```
    private void showData(List<Item> collection)
    {
        gwQuestions.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        gwQuestions.DataSource = addNotSet(collection);

        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in gwQuestions.Rows)
        {
            DataGridViewImageCell cell = row.Cells[2] as DataGridViewImageCell;
            cell.ValueType = typeof(System.Drawing.Image);
            if (collection[row.Index].Result)
            {
                cell.Value = (System.Drawing.Image)Properties.Resources.Check;
            }
            else
            {
                cell.Value = (System.Drawing.Image)Properties.Resources.Cancel;
            }
        }
    }
```

But in grid i show only red cross on paper, like File not found error.
Can you help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work if you put your logic to assign the image within the CellFormatting event of the DataGridView:

```
dataGridView1.CellFormatting += dataGridView1_CellFormatting;

void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{            
    if (dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "ImageColumnName")
    {
        if (collection[e.RowIndex].Result)
        {
            e.Value = (System.Drawing.Image)Properties.Resources.Check;
        }
        else
        {
            e.Value = (System.Drawing.Image)Properties.Resources.Cancel;
        }
    }
}
```

Also note that you set e.Value rather than cell.Value here.

Answer (score 0):

Salvete!  I was looking for a similar answer.  If you don't mind my vb, try this post (where I answered myself...).  The code shows how to load an image from resource into a `datagridview.`

[How to dynamically swap a string for an image in Datagridview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8622883/how-to-dynamically-swap-a-string-for-an-image-in-datagridview/8626980#8626980)