# How to dynamically swap a string for an image in Datagridview?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

Salvete!  In my windows form I have an empty `datagridview` that contains strings loaded from a csvfile.  The `datagridview` has no initial column collection.  There are four columns in the csv file.  In the csv file, columns 1 and 2 have values of `true` or`false`.  So far I am able to load the text perfectly.

What I want to do is change the strings "true" or "false" into an image in my resources (a pretty green checkmark and a red x).

I would like to leave the csv file text as it is, and then change the columns dynamically.

Then, when I save the information back to the csv file, the images must be converted to text strings to accomodate the csv.

Thanks to anyone who can help me!

Answer (score 1):

Salvete!  Okay, after some grueling agony, I figured it out.

First, I hard-coded the column structure in the form, instead of loading it dynamically.  I won't ever need more column data in the csv file, so this is an option for me.  But this allows me to specify exactly which columns are image columns and which are text columns, and it lets me do all of that in VS's GUI designer.

As I loaded the csv, I created two extra image columns and set their corresponding data values to not visible.

Later, when I save the csv file, I skip the image rows and save what is in the data rows.

```
Private Sub ImportCSV(ByVal whatgrid As DataGridView, ByVal whatfile As String)
    Dim TextLine As String = ""
    Dim SplitLine() As String
    whatgrid.Rows.Clear()
    Dim thisobject0 As Object
    Dim thisobject1 As Object
    If System.IO.File.Exists(whatfile) = True Then
        Dim objReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(whatfile)
        Do While objReader.Peek() <> -1
            TextLine = objReader.ReadLine()
            SplitLine = Split(TextLine, ",")
            If SplitLine(0) = "false" Then thisobject0 = My.Resources.markfalse Else If SplitLine(0) = "true" Then thisobject0 = My.Resources.marktrue Else thisobject0 = My.Resources.blank
            If SplitLine(1) = "false" Then thisobject1 = My.Resources.markfalse Else If SplitLine(1) = "true" Then thisobject1 = My.Resources.marktrue Else thisobject1 = My.Resources.blank
            whatgrid.Rows.Add(thisobject0, SplitLine(0), thisobject1, SplitLine(1), SplitLine(2), SplitLine(3))
        Loop
        objReader.Close()
        blankNewRow()
    Else
        MsgBox("File Does Not Exist")
    End If
End Sub
```